Read Text Displayed in Top Right Corner of Bar Chart for X Axis Value
I am trying to access the text displayed in the upper right corner of a bar chart for the Y value.  I can get the coordinates but not the text.  My goal is to get the text on a click on a bar and then call another plot or display a dataframe with details (drilldown).  I am open to suggestions, including using other libraries like plotly.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import mplcursors

def addlabels(x,y):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        plt.text(i, y[i]//2,y[i], ha = 'center')

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\XXXXX\OneDrive\TOP20.csv', usecols=['Name', 'MaxRAM'])
df2 = df
name_list = df2['Name'].tolist()
maxram_list = df2['MaxRAM'].tolist()
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(x=name_list, y=maxram_list)])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bars = ax.barh(name_list, maxram_list)
ax.bar_label(bars)
def on_hover(sel):
   x_val = sel.target[0]
   y_val = sel.target[1]
   sel.annotation.set_text(f'x: {x_val:.2f}, y: {y_val:.2f}')
cursor = mplcursors.cursor(bars, hover=True)
cursor.connect("add", on_hover)

def on_click(event):
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        for bar in bars:
            if bar.contains(event)[0]:
                x_coords = np.arange(len(name_list))
                x_val = bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2
                y_val = bar.get_height()
                label = bar.get_label()
                print(f'Clicked bar: {label}, Value: {y_val}')
          
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)

plt.show()

Output when a bar is clicked:
Clicked bar: nolegend, Value: 0.8

Tried various ways to access the text for the Y coordinate.

You could try something likename_list[int(round(bar.get_y()))]. And something similar for y_val in on_hover(...).

Please remove the references to plotly and the call to go.Figure().  Plotly is a very different library, that doesn't work together with matplotlib.

The reason you’re getting _nolegend_ instead of the actual label is that you haven’t set the labels for the bars.
You can do this by using the bar.set_label() method, like this:
for bar in bars:
    i = bars.index(bar)
    bar.set_label(name_list[i]) 

Once done, you’ll be able to fetch the label using the get_label() method. To display another plot with a drilldown view of the clicked bar, you can modify your existing on_click() function like this:
def on_click(event):
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        for bar in bars:
            if bar.contains(event)[0]:
                name = bar.get_label() 
                maxram = bar.get_height()  
                fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
                ax2.set_title(f'Drilldown for {name}')
                ax2.text(0.5, 0.5, f'Clicked Bar: {name}\nValue: {maxram}GB',
                         transform=ax2.transAxes, ha='center', fontsize=12, color='blue')
                ax2.axis('off') 
                plt.show()
                break

This should help you achieve what you need. Also, as mentioned by @JohanC in the comments, please remove any references to plotly, as that’s a very different library, and your goal can be accomplished with matplotlib and mplcursors alone.
(Note: You can also use the enumerate() function to simplify the for loop used for setting the labels.)

Note also for bar, name in zip(bars, name_list): bar.set_label(name) — (Python snobs have no use for indices)
